# Issues with rendering html emails

Tags: php, html-email, imap, email-client

I'm trying to build a small PHP app. In the section of the app, users can view emails from their inbox. The problem I have is the emails are not rendered correctly.

So it renders the emails but I end up seeing the css and basic html code of emails. Images are not also being loaded. Here is my code

```
<?php

use Mustache_Engine;
use Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader;
require_once '/home/dashboard/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = '{test severy:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'XXX@gmail';
$password = 'password';


$mailbox = imap_open($server, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to the server: ' . imap_last_error());


$loader = new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('/home/dashboard');
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine(['loader' => $loader]);

$totalMessages = imap_num_msg($mailbox);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalMessages; $i++) {
    $header = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $i);
    $messageBody = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $i, 1);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $i);
    $isHTML = ($structure->type == 2 && $structure->subtype == 'HTML');

    
    $cleanedContent = strip_tags($messageBody, '<p><a><strong><em><u><br><img>');

    echo '<strong>From:</strong> ' . $header->fromaddress . '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Subject:</strong> ' . htmlspecialchars($header->subject) . '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Date:</strong> ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($header->date)) . '<br>';

    echo '<strong>Message:</strong><br>';
    if ($isHTML) {
       
        $template = $mustache->loadTemplate('email-template.mustache');
        $renderedContent = $template->render([
            'subject' => htmlspecialchars($header->subject),
            'messageBody' => '<style>' . $cleanedContent . '</style>',
        ]);

        echo $renderedContent;
    } else {
        // Plain text content
        echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($cleanedContent));
    }

    echo '<hr>';
}

imap_close($mailbox);
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. I had to remove commentin the code so whole text can get in

Here are the images:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image 3]

I have tried to use template like Mustache_Engine yet the emails are not rendering fine.

Comment: What is the purpose of `strip_tags` in your code ?

Comment: Agreed, try without strip_tags, I'm not sure why you would want that. Foe example that code removes all image tags from the content, so the fact images then aren't displaying shouldn't be a big surprise

Comment: Even without the stripe tags they don't display. The strip tags were meant to brush the rendering so it doesn't display raw CSS code

Comment: @Sargin strip_tags would only make that problem worse, not better, by removing bits of valid html but leaving debris behind.

Comment: Anyway if images don't display you need to start to dig into why that is. Maybe the img tag is not output correctly into the page? Or maybe the link in the tag is wrong? Or maybe a permission issue when trying to fetch the image? Use your browser's Developer Tools to examine what's really going on. You've only given us pictures of the problem and haven't provided any sample of the raw html of any of these emails (i.e. the raw string in `$messageBody` you get from the email server), or your mustache template, so we can only do a limited amount of investigation here...

Comment: ...so if you require more detailed assistance from the community after you've done your own investigations you would need to update your post to ensure it's a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Sure. Here is the code that renders the raw content: https://pastebin.com/cdv7AAW1 You can see that it displays the raw HTML content here: https://dashboard.getsend.online/ap.php

Comment: @ADyson, please check it out when you have time

Comment: Thanks. That isn't actually what I asked you to provide. You've already shown us the PHP code, above, and the link just shows the text "MX Records not found. SPF Records not found. DMARC Records not found.". I asked for the _raw_ content of $messageBody _before_ you do anything to it, and also the code of your mustache template.

Comment: Also what debugging have you done yourself? Are you quite sure that `$isHTML` is `true` for example? Is it definitely going down that path rather than thinking the email is plain-text and then html-encoding it (which would easily cause the symptoms you mention). Have you double-checked things like that?